# "Provider not a subtype" on org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog for Embedded Jetty

Tags: scala, maven, jetty, embedded-jetty

When using embedded jetty and started via

```
mvn jetty:run
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
```

Here is the `pom.xml` snippets:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.v201112011016</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.19.v20160209</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.19.v20160209</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any pointers to a correctly configured embedded jetty (preferably also using websockets) appreciated.

Comment: [Jetty 8 is EOL](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html)(End of Life).  Consider upgrading.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt The problem is I am using scala websocket examples. There are none available for  Jetty 9.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to enable everything all at once.

Jetty is a *highly* modular system, you can pick and choose what you want to run.  Nothing is mandatory by default, even the Server!

If you want examples of embedded jetty with websockets, consider reviewing the example projects that the Jetty project has put together at ...

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-websocket-echo-examples

Some advice:

- Build up your requirements layer by layer
- Start with basic websocket endpoint functionality (get this working first!)
- then add slf4j + logback. (be sure you use an appropriate version, see the `<scope>optional</scope>` dependencies present in your previous layer before you choose a version of slf4j or logback).  Test this like there is no tommorrow.
- then add [jsp support](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp) (as your error seems to indicate your desire for jsp support)

Comment: Actually I am trying to use Scala .. The problem is I can not seem to find any examples for Jetty 9.

Comment: The only scala example I can find is using jetty 8  https://github.com/qtamaki/websocket-jetty-scala/blob/master/build.sbt